# typescript generic array of union type does not conform

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a generic class whose generic parameter extends a union of array.

```js
interface BaseConfig {
    name: string;
}

interface ValidationConfig<T = any> extends BaseConfig {
    validate: (param: T) => boolean;
}

class Test<T extends BaseConfig[] | ValidationConfig[]> {
    constructor(public configs: readonly [...T]) { }
}
// should raise an error, because two objects's type doesn't conform
const test = new Test([
    {
        name: "test1",
        validator: (a: number) => true,
    },
    {
        name: "test2",
    }
] as const);
```

When I instantiate `Test`, I expect `configs` is either `BaseConfig[]` or `ValidationConfig[]`. However TS allows me to pass in two different types.

The purpose I used rest type parameter is that I need to extract `name` later.

```js
type ValidateType<T> = {
    type: "random"
} | {
    type: "validate";
    param: T
}

class Test<T extends BaseConfig[] | ValidationConfig[]> {
    constructor(public configs: readonly [...T]) { }

    // I expect arg's type is ValidateType<never> if T is BaseConfig[], instead of raising an error
    // and can correctly infer T in ValidateType if class T is ValidationConfig[]
    public validate(arg: ValidateType<Parameters<T[number]["validator"]>[0]>): T[number]["name"] | undefined {
        if (arg.type === "random") {
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.configs.length);
            return this.configs[index].name;
        }
        if (arg.type === "validate") {
            // using any here is OK if arg's type is ValidateConf<never>
            const passed = this.configs.find(config => (config as any).validate(arg.param));
            return passed?.name;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

`Test` class is the minimal reproducible example here for my project.

The logic is when I instantiate `Test` with `BaseConfig[]`, you cannot use `type: "validate"` in `validate` func, when I instantiate `Test` with `ValidationConfig[]`, you can use both `"random"` and `"validate"` and TS can correctly infer `T` equal as `T` in `ValidationConfig`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVkKnm)

Comment: `ValidationConfig` extends `BaseConfig`, so it is valid to pass it everywhere a `BaseConfig` would be expected. There really is not much you can do to change the function. You should change the original types to decouple them, so that a `ValidationConfig` is not assignable to a `BaseConfig` anymore.

Comment: @TobiasS. `const arr: BaseConfig[] = [{ name: "", validator: () => {} }]` raises an error, you mean generic constraint is looser than direct assignment?

Comment: There are special rules for direct assignment of literals - See [this Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRPkN). You can assign `ValidationConfig` to a `BaseConfig` in every other way.